# Powershell Test-Connection: different results when run AsJob vs straight-up

Tags: powershell, ping, jobs

***Short version**: Why does `Test-Connection` provide only **one** result when running `-AsJob`?*

---

***Detailed version:***

When the `Test-Connection` (ping!) command is run in Powershell (running as Administrator) it uses the default value of `4` for the `Count` parameter. This gives me the expected results (some irrelevant data removed for clarity):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-Connection www.stackoverflow.com

Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address   Bytes    Time(ms) 
-----------     -----------      -----------   -----    -------- 
www.stackove... 64.34.119.12     {}            32       117      
www.stackove... 64.34.119.12     {}            32       113      
www.stackove... 64.34.119.12     {}            32       111      
www.stackove... 64.34.119.12     {}            32       113
```

However, when I run it with the `-AsJob` flag, it seems (when running `Receive-Job`, after waiting a few secs) the `Count` was only 1, but I expected it to be 4 and get similar results as above. Instead I get this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-Connection www.stackoverflow.com -AsJob

Id         Name            State      HasMoreData     Location     Command        
--         ----            -----      -----------     --------     -------        
1          Job1            Running    False           .            Test-Connection

PS C:\Windows\system32> Receive-Job 1

Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address   Bytes    Time(ms) 
-----------     -----------      -----------   -----    -------- 
www.stackove... 64.34.119.12     {}            32       113
```

The `AsJob` variant **always** returns one row, *even if you provide a specific value for `Count`*.

My Google-fu and [Get-Help-fu](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd347597.aspx) don't seem to be sufficient. Can someone please explain what's going on here, preferably with some pointers how and where to find this info myself (e.g. which help files or sources explain this behavior)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a bug. In v3 you get back 4 pings.

Comment: Oi, that is one explanation I hadn't considered yet!

Comment: Submitted it as [a bug on MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/750000/test-connection-different-results-when-run-asjob-vs-straight-up), I'll probably get back here and accept the answer in a while, if no one turns up with a different explanation. Thx for your insight!

Comment: I'm just going to assume this is it, and accept the answer. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: MS confirmed this on the mentioned MS Connect Bug report.